# OpenGL/Freeglut in Eclipse Problems - Includes Not Being Found?

Tags: c++, eclipse, windows, opengl

I am trying to configure OpenGL/Freeglut in Eclipse on Windows. I have installed MinGW as my toolchain, and the Environment maps MINGW_HOME to the correct top level directory on my C:/ Drive (C:/MingGW). My project lists the various includes in the Project Explorer, including the relevant one to my purpose, C:/MinGW/include.

C:/MinGW/include/GL has all the Freeglut header files which detail the functions I want to use as expected. In particular, C:/MinGW/include/GL/glut.h is definitely where it is expected. My simple test code is below:

```
#include <windows.h>  // For MS Windows
#include <GL/glut.h>

void display() {
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f); // Set background color to black and opaque
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);         // Clear the color buffer

// Draw a Red 1x1 Square centered at origin
glBegin(GL_QUADS);              // Each set of 4 vertices form a quad
  glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // Red
  glVertex2f(-0.5f, -0.5f);    // x, y
  glVertex2f( 0.5f, -0.5f);
  glVertex2f( 0.5f,  0.5f);
  glVertex2f(-0.5f,  0.5f);
glEnd();

glFlush();  // Render now
} 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
   glutInit(&argc, argv);                 // Initialize GLUT
   glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Setup Test"); // Create a window with the given title
   glutInitWindowSize(320, 320);   // Set the window's initial width & height
   glutInitWindowPosition(50, 50); // Position the window's initial top-left corner
   glutDisplayFunc(display); // Register display callback handler for window re-paint
   glutMainLoop();           // Enter the infinitely event-processing loop
   return 0;
}
```

None of the functions (except glutInit and glutCreateWindow) are recognized by the program, despite the include lines. What might be causing this? Is there a step I have missed in my configuration?

Please ask if any further details required.

**UPDATE:** Situation improved. Not sure how to link to the libraries freeglut_std.h requires, as three functions in it (listed in comment below) are throwing errors, but do not appear to be in explicit use. Any advice?

Comment: You might also need to include <GL\gl.h>

Comment: That helped! However, I still have three undefined references, which happen in an external library that I am not using (freeglut_std.h). I have tried to link to it, but so far, no luck. The errors are related to:

freeglut_std.h|620|undefined reference to `_imp____glutInitWithExit@12'|
freeglut_std.h|622|undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateWindowWithExit@8'|
freeglut_std.h|624|undefined reference to `_imp____glutCreateMenuWithExit@8'|

Comment: According to http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/computing/using-glut-with-mingw/ you should be including <GL\freeglut.h> instead of <GL\glut.h>. If I recall correctly freeglut.h includes glut.h and does some other things as well.

Comment: I fixed the errors! It's obscure, but I found a suggestion to include the following define before #include <GL/glut.h> in my code:

#define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK

And it worked! Thanks to all for your assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by including the #define GLUT_DISABLE_ATEXIT_HACK define before the #include  header!